# Django массовое добавление многий ко многим

Tags: python, django, django-model

Есть 2 модели

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_path = models.CharField("image path", max_length=300, unique=True)
    image_name = models.CharField("image name", max_length=30)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", verbose_name=("tags"))


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField("tag", max_length=20, unique=True)
```

Обе заполняются через `bulk_create`. Надо массово связать `Image` и `Tag`.
Что-то типа этого:

```
for tag in Tag.objects.all():
        Image.objects.filter(image_path__contains=os.sep + tag.tag + os.sep).update(tags=tag)
```

При этом если изображение уже имеет связь с тегом повторно её создавать не надо.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил сам ответил =)

```py
for tag in Tag.objects.all():
    tag.image_set.add(*Image.objects.filter(image_path__contains=os.sep + tag.tag + os.sep))
```

Дубли при этом не создаются.